# Access iframe content head using asp.net or javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, iframe

I created an asp.net page with an iframe. The iframe has a HTML page. Now I am referring the HTML content via the url `Admin/Home.aspx#Personnel_Data`. But it's not working. Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these

docment.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.

document.getElementById('FrameId').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML

document.getElementById('FrameId').contentWindow.document.body.outerHTML

var doc = document.getElementById('FrameId').contentWindow.document;

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp

Comment: add a function

function AccessiFrame() {
var doc = document.getElementById('FrameId').contentWindow.document;
var innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
alert(innerHTML);
//or assign to some where else
or find the specific element in doc object
}

Comment: Please do not use w3schools as a reference! It is usually really bad: http://w3fools.com

Comment: I do not see any point in your comment. If the information correct and available ofcourse I will use it.